# Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess'

Tags: c#, windows-services, config, oracle-manageddataaccess

we are developing a windows service which connect to oracle database. We use
Oracle ManagedDataAccess from Nuget package.
When running the windows service we are receving below error. Tried to get details from stackoverflows and nothing is able to resolve the problem.
Our config file is as below

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess,
>   Version=4.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'
>   or one of its dependencies

Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="eClaimsService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client"
      type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
   <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
        type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="10240"/>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60"/>
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

---

Comment: did you check if the `.dll` is present in the `bin` path where the service is pointed at ?

Comment: @HariHaran yes, it is there and we copied to the service local path too

Comment: Try adding the `dll` to the `gac` and re-start the service

Comment: Afaik Oracle dlls were either 32bit or 64 bit. Check if it works if your code is compiled explicitly for x86 or x64.

Answer (score 0):

In my case just go to Visual Studio 20xx Developer Command Prompt and open as Administrator.

Then run the command
`C:\Windows\System32>gacutil /u Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`
And you are able to uninstall the data successfully.

Now I am able to access application without any error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when my App.Config contained an old version of the DLL, I just removed this entry from the App.Config and it worked